# Configuring Rails Asset Pipeline in dev and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am still not quite sure about the best practice of using rails asset pipeline. In a rails skeleton project, the application.html.erb contains code as:

```
<head>
  <title>My title</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "scaffolds" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "depot", media: "all"  %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Now in development, all js and css would be served properly. But in production, after precompile all the asset (js and css), I only need application.css and application.js, as scaffolds.css and depot.css are concatenate in application.css. So scaffolds.css and depot.css are no longer needed in production.

How could I have the above code in dev and then in production, have asset pipeline know certain assets have been concatenated in application.css/js and then remove those asset link tag in the code?

If this is not possible, how should I avoid loading redundant resources and keeping prod deployment manageable? (meaning no deleting the link_tag manually in production)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not put

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "scaffolds" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "depot", media: "all"  %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
```

in your layout file. You only put

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
```

And in `config/environment/development.rb` you make sure you have

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

When `config.assets.debug` is set to `true` it will automatically generate the `<link ... />`  tags for each of your stylesheets in dev mode for each assets required in the `application.css` file's Sprockets directives.

In `config/environment/production.rb` `config.assets.debug` will be `false` by default, causing the assets to be concatenated together into a single `application.css` file *(again, assuming your `//= require` lines are correct in `application.css`)*. This will cause **1**  link tag to be created for only `application.css` in production.